# What should I do about edit suggestions being rejected?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

One of the members who has a higher reputation than me rejects my edits on the wrong basis. I know that on this site, we write *Ubuntu* and not *ubuntu*. Even when I write *ubuntu*, other members correct it. But one user has rejected some of my edits on a wrong basis (I think) and rejects all my edits which change *ubuntu* to *Ubuntu* (or some similar reasons).

- [example 1](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/849996)
- [example 2](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/849993)
- [example 3](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/849990)
- [example 4](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/849991)

Above are my edit suggestions, rejected by this user.

Please tell me if I can do anything about it, or let me know if I've done anything wrong in my edits.

Comment: I approved all of them just now, need approval from another reviewer. Proper capitalisation/spelling does improve a post IMO.

Comment: Note that I have recently asked a [question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17991/what-to-do-with-half-hearted-edit-suggestions) at meta regarding the best practice to deal with edits which fix capitalisation/spelling/punctuation etc. **but** leave out bigger, glaring issues with the post.

Comment: Approved. I have nothing to add to what pomsky wrote above.

Comment: @Zanna In the first example, 12 mistakes are corrected, but the edit was rejected by that user, I don't think that's a minor edit. Thanks, I'll improve my edits.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry sorry. I misunderstood based on the content of your question. We can argue about the majorness or otherwise of the edits, but this post should reflect your perception of the situation, not mine!

Comment: @Unbesiegbarkeit, some of those suggestions just concentrate on Upper case/lower case while ignoring real readability issues like overly long passages without paragraph/line breaks. I wouldn't have rejected them though (probably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm the joker who also has the highest score [on the other edit question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17991/what-to-do-with-half-hearted-edit-suggestions)  and this does not seem to be answered, I'll throw in my 0,02€:

1. Edit the very unclear, difficult questions that need a lot of help first
2. Leave the small edits where you just change 1 character to when you've reached 2000 rep (back in the stone age, when I was a beginning user, that's what had to be done, but the rules might have changed in the meantime)
3. Once you've become a reviewer and not an editor, *don't forget how difficult it was to be a beginning user!*  **:-)**
4. Don't edit just to format until you've reached 2000 rep.
5. Translate if you speak multiple languages
6. Change the sentence construction if it makes things clearer
7. incorporate comments into questions / answers
8. ***Don't be exasperated by one single user who's just taken 10 minutes to edit one question or answer and then sees one that took 2 minutes: he's as human as you.*** (I'm not: I'm an alien being made out of pure energy)

## ;-)

<sub><sup>P.S. and don't forget to think! Cogito ergo sum! **:D**</sup></sub>

Comment: I have to disagree with this point though `Don't edit just to format until you've reached 2000 rep`. For minor formatting, I agree. But IMHO, formatting edits are just as good as fixing grammar or other issues. I'd even argue that fixing formatting in some cases are even more important than any other edits.

Comment: After 2000 Rep, you don't get any rep for editing any more, and then you *can* edit just one character...

Comment: Yes I agree about minor formatting, but check this [edit suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/853772), it's just an edit that fixes formatting, but I would consider it a really good one. Makes the post a lot more readable.

Comment: @Dan I'm sorry to disagree.  You only changed the formatting and made it only slightly better but not worthy of an upvote.  Please see my comment below the answer and the comments I left for the OP inside his answer.  It still needs a lot of improvement and that's my entire point: help the N00bs become better people **;-)** and don't just reformat their questions or answers...  **0:-)**

Comment: No need to be sorry ;) I respect your opinion. However, I would argue that editing should be collaborative, I wouldn't ask anyone to fully edit every mistake in a post (especially newcomers), very few people can do that.  Please keep in mind, I'm only talking about this point `Don't edit just to format until you've reached 2000 rep.` and when an edit makes a post more readable.